# Find the angle $\alpha$''

Tags: geometry

probably it is an easy problem but I can not find a general rule for all the cases. You can check the Geometry problem illustration here:

[image]

, what I need is to find the only unknown variable that I have $\alpha$'' which is the the angle between the vectors `V'` and `X`. The given values are $\alpha$ which is angle between the vectors `V` and `X` as well as $\alpha$' angle between `V` and `V'`, The magnitude of every vector is known also.

Comment: Angles of triangle add up to $180^\circ$. This should give you $\alpha + \alpha ' = \alpha ''$

Answer (score 1):

**If one side of any ∆ is produced, then exterior angle = sum of two opposite interior angles**

Use the above theorem as you stated that $ \alpha , \alpha ' $ are both known!

$ \alpha ' $ makes vertically opposite angle & $ \alpha '' $ is the exterior angle.

$$ \alpha '' = \alpha ' + \alpha $$

Comment: But $\alpha$'' is not the exterior angle in other cases, in fact $\alpha$'' could be interior and $\alpha$ could be exterior angle in other cases.

Comment: But for this case? @starter

Comment: for the case I stated it should be $\alpha$ - $\alpha$' =$\alpha$''.